# How to force recalculation of NavigationView in Android and Wasm?

Tags: c#, android, webassembly, uno-platform

Currently, the NavigationView is not rendered correctly in Android and Wasm if you are working with visibility bindings.

As far as I know, the NavigationView is in an unstable state, but maybe someone knows a workaround for this problem like forcing a UI recalculation with the current binding/visibility values.

[image]

Update with code sample:

```
<NavigationView ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked" PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" PaneOpened="NavigationView_PaneOpened" IsSettingsVisible="False" IsBackEnabled="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
 <NavigationView.MenuItems>
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNew" Tag="createnew" Content="CREATENEW" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewDrillZ2" Tag="createnewdrillz2" Content="DRILLZ2" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewDrillZ3" Tag="createnewdrillz3" Content="DRILLZ3" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewDrillStepZ2" Tag="createnewdrillstepz2" Content="DRILLSTEPZ2" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewCutterZ2" Tag="createnewcutterz2" Content="CUTTERZ2" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewCutterZ3R" Tag="createnewcutterz3r" Content="CUTTERZ3R" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewCutterZ4B" Tag="createnewcutterz4b" Content="CUTTERZ4B" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonNewCutterFormZ3" Tag="createnewcutterformz3" Content="CUTTERFORMZ3" Visibility="{Binding IsChooseNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItemSeparator Visibility="{Binding CanOpenShared, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonOpenShared" Tag="openshared" Content="OPENSHARED" Visibility="{Binding CanOpenShared, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItemSeparator Visibility="{Binding IsEditingTool, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonEdit" Tag="edit" Content="EDIT" Visibility="{Binding IsEditingTool, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonView2D" Tag="view2d" Content="VIEW2D" Visibility="{Binding IsEditingTool, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonView3D" Tag="view3d" Content="VIEW3D" Visibility="{Binding IsEditingTool, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonShare" Tag="share" Content="SHARE" Visibility="{Binding IsEditingTool, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  <NavigationViewItemSeparator />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonSettings" Tag="settings" Content="SETTINGS" />
  <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ButtonAbout" Tag="about" Content="ABOUT" />
 </NavigationView.MenuItems>
 <Frame Name="RootFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: Do you have code to share? :)

Comment: I can add some XAML code on monday, but it should be sufficient to add several menu items in the NavigationView and change their visibility by different bindings, like `Visibility="{Binding MyVisibility}"`.

Comment:  can you please raise a issue over at https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/new?labels=kind%2Fbug%2C+triage%2Funtriaged&template=bug-report.md and attach a repro? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of `Uno.UI`? I made few fixes last week for the calculator project (https://calculator.platform.uno/). Updating the UI on some events - mostly _loaded_ - were producing `Collection has been modified` exceptions. It was happening on all uno supported platforms, but the result was worst on Android.

Since it was producing random unexpected results, it could explain you problem here. The fix has been published in `Uno.UI v.1.46.0-dev.2288`.

Comment: I just installed the latest package from NUGET. Problem: There is a version "feature.iosTouches" which is alphabetically before the actual latest version, so Visual Studio tries to update to that older build 2253 instead of 2294. Yet, I am sorry, but the bug is not fixed.

Comment: The iostouches package has been unlisted.  Try again now please.

Comment: Today, I made some further tests. Unfortunately, the issue persists in the latest build "1.46.202-dev.2500".